# Not able to concatenate string in python

Tags: python, for-loop, range, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate filename strings to cat the names of the files as below.
But somehow the sting is not getting concatenated.  I also tried += operator.

```
import os
from io import StringIO
ca_cert_file_string = ""
def create_ca_cert_file():
    num1 = os.system("ls ca.crt* | wc -l")
    num =  int (num1)

    concat = StringIO()
    for i in range(0,num):
    str = "ca.crt-%d " %i
    concat.write(str)

    ca_cert_file_string = "cat %s > tls_ca_cert" %concat.getvalue()
    return ca_cert_file_string

str  = create_ca_cert_file()
print str
```

I get output as 3 where as I want `concat.getvalue()` to print `ca.crt-0 ca.crt1 ca.crt-2 ca.crt-4`

```
599> python test4.py
3
cat  > tls_ca_cert
```

Comment: Untested: `' '.join(glob.glob('ca.cert*'))`

Comment: maybe wrongly indented code? your code looks fine other than the indent